# Add and display MKOverlay when MKAnnotation has been tapped

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkoverlay

Is possible to add an `MKOverlay` when the user taps an `MKAnnotation`? I.e., what I want to achieve is when the user taps the annotation pin, I want to draw a polygon (a circle for example), and when the user taps again the overlay should hide.

Answer (score 0):

If annotation was tapped call function with adding overlay. Use this in your code:

```
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.circle];
```

for controll if annotation was tapped already, i would use BOOL variable in your interface:

```
@interface ClassName() {
    BOOL annotationWasTapped;
}
@end
```